# How could I make sure the covariance matrix of conditional multivariate normal is positive defined?

Tags: gaussian-process

I am trying to simulate some data to fit a Gaussian Process and then evaluate `p(f_x^* | y_{x},x)` in some new test point `x^*`. The conditional property of multivariate normal is below:

[image]

How could I make sure the second term (Sigma_12 X Sigma_22^T X Sigma_21) of covariance matrix is not larger than the first term(Sigma_11).

(:(I am sorry for the bad notation since I dont know how to write Latex format here).

I am trying to use the conditional mean and covariance matrix to sample using mvrnorm in R but it sometime give me error that `'Sigma' is not positive definite`.